# How to make label show up on second window with python tinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Why is the label not showing up when I run the code?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() # instantiates an instance of a window object
root.title("first app")
root.geometry("420x420")

def addition():
window2 = Toplevel()
window2.geometry('420x420')
label2 = Label(window2, text="fts")
label2.pack()
window2.mainloop()

addition_button = Button(root, text="addition", command=addition)

addition_button.pack()

root.mainloop() # runs the window
```

I tried a few things and nothing would work

Comment: FYI, you do not need a second `mainloop`. If I fix the indentation errors then a second window with the `Label` shows up with "fts" on it after pressing the `Button`.

Comment: When I run your code the label shows up in a second window when I press the button. Though the indentation on your code is broken so I had to guess, and maybe guessed wrong. @Rory is right, though -- you shouldn't call `mainloop` a second time.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me, I just indented your addition() function correctly.
I also removed the second mainloop that could potentially cause your problem and everything works fine.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() # instantiates an instance of a window object
root.title("first app")
root.geometry("420x420")

def addition():
    window2 = Toplevel()
    window2.geometry('420x420')
    label2 = Label(window2, text="fts")
    label2.pack()

addition_button = Button(root, text="addition", command=addition)

addition_button.pack()

root.mainloop() # runs the window
```